# checking quotes matches in regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a Regex with the following rule.

**Text on which Regex match needs to be done:**

```
Key: "employeeNo" with value "ABC12345" is already used.
```

**Rule:**

```
 1. Only the number after ABC is changing.

 2. Key: "employeeNo" with value "ABC[Any Number with any length]" is
    already used.
```

**True cases**

```
Key: "employeeNo" with value "ABC12345" is already used.
Key: "employeeNo" with value "ABC987858547" is already used.
Key: "employeeNo" with value "ABC7" is already used.
```

**Falsecases**

```
key is not used
Key: "employeeNo" with value "ABCXYZYZ" is already used.
Key: employeeNo with value ABC7 is already used.
```

Regex tried

**`Key: "employeeNo" with value "ABC[0-9]+" is already used.`**

I also want to check quotes "".

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please clarify. What language/tool you're using and what do you mean with `I also want to check quotes`?

Comment: @HamZa.Sorry for confusion, I have updated the question. I am using Java. I also want to check for quotes "". Can you help me.

Comment: What do you mean? Where's the problem? Could you provide one or two input with the expected output?

Comment: @HamZa. I have updated the question with expected outputs. Can you check

Comment: Are you escaping the period?

Comment: So what's not working? Your regex seems fine.

Comment: [Everything works fine](http://regex101.com/r/oC9xU7), you might just escape the dot `.` since it will match anything (except newline).

Comment: I recommend playing around at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html.  There are many great sites like this to debug regex.

Comment: @HamZa. I forgot to escape . char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks simple enough, you need to escape your double quotes.

```
String input = "Key: \"employeeNo\" with value \"ABC12345\" is already used.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Key: \"employeeNo\" with value \"(ABC\\d+)\" is already used.");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
Key: "employeeNo" with value "ABC12345" is already used.
ABC12345
```

If you need the double quotes *inside* the back-referenced group (group 1), just enclose the escaped double-quotes in the group parenthesis: `(\"ABC\\d+\")`.